# Viewport vs Render lighting dramatically different

Tags: lighting

[image]

I have no clue why on earth this is happening. My viewport vs render lighting are just wildly different and I cant seem to figure out why.

I have a few lights in my scene, which I've now turned off and bumped only one of them up to see if I can tell what's going on but still nothing.

I cant see any hidden objects, or things that would be blocking the light. I also had a volume cube which I tried rendering with/without but it doesn't seem to be the cause.

My lights have a node set up connected to a blackbody node - I disconnected this and still same result from render.

I have to say the viewport in the screenshot isn't the "final" look - as I mentioned I have a proper lighting set up for this scene, I just isolated 1 light in front of the figure and bumped up the light so I can clearly see any discrepancies.

Comment: Hello are you sure that you've enabled the light for render in the Outliner? Maybe share your file (remove the useless objects)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: hey - in the screenshot the outliner shows all of the lights, and all of the lights that are enabled/disabled. I just got someone from a discord server to open the file, and they dont seem to have this problem. No idea why. I reopened my blender file and its still doing the exact same thing. There are no useless objects, the scene is comprised of everything you see in the screenshot - a pole, a figure, lighting, camera. thats it.

Comment: OK maybe share the file nevertheless?

Comment: The icons in the _Outliner_ show that the lights are animated. What animations are there? Can they be responsible for the behaviour?

Comment: Also you have a full *Collection* only visible in viewport (*DAZ_HIDE*).